# How to search piped data in Global Search PrimeNg table Angular?

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable

We have a table and I already pipe one column.But when I search,it search actual data,piped data not show in table.
Global Search:

```
 <p-table [globalFilterFields]="['value']"  [responsive]="true" responsiveLayout="stack"  (onFilter)="handleFilter($event)"  styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines"  editMode="row"  #dt  [exportHeader]="'customExportHeader'"  [(selection)]="selectedProducts"   rowGroupMode="rowspan" groupRowsBy="dateOfRelease" sortField="dateOfRelease"   dataKey="ldId"  [columns]="cols"    [showCurrentPageReport]="true"  sortMode="multiple" [value]="formatData"   (sortFunction)="customSort($event)"
        [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"   [loading]="loading" >
```

//Global Search Code:

```
<input pInputText type="text"   (input)="dt.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value,'contains')" (onChange)="onwireVersionChange($event)"  placeholder="Global Search" />
    
//Custom Method for global filter:
   

 public prepareFilters(): void {
            this.wireVersionFilters=[];
            this.formatData.forEach((filtered)=>{
              console.log("Filtered",filtered)
              const wireVersionFilter: DataFilter = {value:filtered.value, label:new WireVersionPipe().transform(filtered.value)};
              this.wireVersionFilters.findIndex(current => current.value === wireVersionFilter.value) === -1 ? this.wireVersionFilters.push(wireVersionFilter) : null;
        
            })
          }
      
      public onwireVersionChange(event:any) {
        const selectedValues = event.value.map((datatableFilter:any) => datatableFilter.value);
        this.table.filter(selectedValues, 'wireVersion', 'in');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this demo together on Stackblitz to handle the same issue I was having. You need to have a custom filter option to handle searching on the original data that will filter it the way you did to the display in order to find the matches.

The difference actually would be that you would need to on the global searching handle the data all the time when searching to correct the data on search to find it.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-filterservice-demo-guymyn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)